# Failed to create a 3rd dimension to 2D dots animation

Tags: matlab, animation, 3d, visualization, scatter3d

I have a code that animates dots moving in random directions in a 2D space (x and y axis). I tried to create a 3rd dimension (z axis) using spherical coordinates In order to draw and display the dots in a 3D space, I used the Psychtoolbox function moglDrawDots3D, as it takes 3d coordinates XYZ, but I am still getting a 2D animation, the dots on the z don't appear. I have no clue on the cause. I am very new to Matlab and animations, I'd be very grateful to get your feedback and insight. I tried to explain my code step by step below for the sake of clarity. Thank you in advance for your help!

PS: The use of the Psychtoolbox is not a necessity, if you have any other solution, I'd be happy to try it out.

```
AssertOpenGL;
InitializeMatlabOpenGL;
display = OpenWindow()
dots.nDots = 531;                       % number of dots
dots.color = [255,255,255];             % color of the dots
dots.size = 10;                         % size of dots (pixels)
dots.center = [0,0,0];                  % center of the field of dots (x,y,z)
dots.apertureSize = [50.8,28.5,50.8];   % size of rectangular aperture [w,h,depth] in degrees
```

First, random position within the aperture for each of the dots. 'dots.x' and 'dots.y' will hold the x and y positions for each dot.

```
[dots.x,dots.y,dots.z] = CreateUniformDotsIn3DFrustum(dots.nDots, 25, 1/screen_ratio, 0.1, 100);
```

Then I converted these dot positions from a visual angle into pixel coordinates using a created function 'angle2pix'

```
tmp = Screen('Resolution',0);                       % (1) Screen's 'Resolution' function determine the screen resolution.
display.resolution = [tmp.width,tmp.height];
display.width = 50.8;                               % (2) Width of the screen in cm.
display.dist = 50;                                  % (3) Distance of the screen from the observer in cm.
```

This generates pixel positions, but they're centered at [0,0], which is the top left corner

```
pixpos.x = angle2pix(display,dots.x);               % Convert the x position of the dots from visual angle to pixel.
pixpos.y = angle2pix(display,dots.y);               % Convert the y position of the dots from visual angle to pixel.
pixpos.z = ones(1, dots.nDots) * -1;
```

I defined some timing and motion parameters for the animation

```
dots.speed = 3;                             % degrees/second
dots.duration = 10;                         % seconds                                                         
dots.theta_deg = randi(360,1,dots.nDots);   % degrees 
dots.phi_deg = 30;                          % degrees 
dots.theta_rad = dots.theta_deg * pi /180;  % direction converted to radians
dots.phi_rad = dots.phi_deg * pi /180;      % direction converted to radians
```

I calculated the distance travelled by the dot, by determining the x,y and z positions using spherical coordinates and then their derivate.

```
dx = dots.speed* sin(-dots.phi_rad-dots.theta_rad)/display.frameRate;
dy = -dots.speed* cos(dots.phi_rad + dots.theta_rad)/display.frameRate;
dz = -dots.speed*cos(dots.theta_rad)/display.frameRate;
```

I try to fit the dots within the aperture by calculating the left, right top, bottom and depth(forward and backward) of the aperture (in degrees)

The total number of frames for the animation is determined by the duration (seconds) multiplied by the frame rate (frames/second). The function secs2frames performs the calculation

```
nFrames = secs2frames(display,dots.duration);

l = dots.center(1)-dots.apertureSize(1)/2;
r = dots.center(1)+dots.apertureSize(1)/2;
b = dots.center(2)-dots.apertureSize(2)/2;
t = dots.center(2)+dots.apertureSize(2)/2;
d_forward = dots.center(3)- dots.apertureSize(3)/2;
d_backward = dots.center(3)+ dots.apertureSize(3)/2;
```

New random starting positions

```
[dots.x,dots.y,dots.z] = CreateUniformDotsIn3DFrustum(dots.nDots, 25, 1/screen_ratio, 0.1, 100);
```

Make the dots move

```
try

    for i=1:nFrames

        %convert from degrees to screen pixels     
        pixpos.x = angle2pix(display,dots.x)+ display.resolution(1)/2;
        pixpos.y = angle2pix(display,dots.y)+ display.resolution(2)/2;
        pixpos.z = ones(1, dots.nDots) * -1;

        moglDrawDots3D(display.windowPtr, [pixpos.x;pixpos.y;pixpos.z],dots.size, dots.color, dots.center,1);
```

update the dot position

```
        dots.x = dots.x + dx;
        dots.y = dots.y + dy;    
        dots.z = dots.z + dz;
```

Move the dots that are outside the aperture back one aperture width

```
     dots.x(dots.x<l) = dots.x(dots.x<l) + dots.apertureSize(1);
        dots.x(dots.x>r) = dots.x(dots.x>r) - dots.apertureSize(1);
        dots.y(dots.y<b) = dots.y(dots.y<b) + dots.apertureSize(2);
        dots.y(dots.y>t) = dots.y(dots.y>t) - dots.apertureSize(2);
        dots.z(dots.z<d_forward) = dots.z(dots.z<d_forward) + dots.apertureSize(3);
        dots.z(dots.z>d_backward) = dots.z(dots.z>d_backward) - dots.apertureSize(3);
        Screen('Flip',display.windowPtr);
    end

catch ME
    Screen('CloseAll');
    rethrow(ME)
end
Screen('CloseAll');
```

Comment: I cannot say if the problem is with how you plot, or with how you compute the motion (perhaps `dz` is always zero, or the aspect ratio is such that although there is motion in the z direction, it's so small in comparison to x and y that it appears not to be moving). I'm very doubtful that your question is answerable in its current form. Is it possible to post a runnable example? You would either need to include all auxiliary functions, or avoid using them (by using some approximations instead). See also: [mre].

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Dev-iL. I put my code, as well as the auxiliary functions in my repo https://github.com/Kathia301m/Matlab-Psychtoolbox.git. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You asked for a suggestion on how to do this differently, so here's a demonstration of a simple 3D animation:

```matlab
function q56758294
%% Generate some data
N_OBJS = 20;
P = rand(N_OBJS,3) .* ones(1,1,3);

%% Create the figure
figure(); 
hP(1) = plot3(P(:,1,1), P(:,2,1), P(:,3,1), 's', 'Color', [0 0 0]+0.8); hold on;
hP(2) = plot3(P(:,1,2), P(:,2,2), P(:,3,2), 's', 'Color', [0 0 0]+0.6);
hP(3) = plot3(P(:,1,3), P(:,2,3), P(:,3,3), 's', 'Color', [0 0 0]);
AX_LIMS = [-1 1]*3;
drawnow; set(gca, 'XLim', AX_LIMS, 'YLim', AX_LIMS, 'ZLim', AX_LIMS); grid on;

%% Animate:
FPS = 12;
for ind1 = 1:500
  % Update coordinates:
  dP = randn(N_OBJS,3)*0.1;
  P(:,:,1) = P(:,:,2);
  P(:,:,2) = P(:,:,3);
  P(:,:,3) = P(:,:,3) + dP;
  
  % Update plot objects:
  for ind2 = 1:3
    set( hP(ind2), 'XData', P(:,1,ind2), 'YData', P(:,2,ind2), 'ZData', P(:,3,ind2) );
  end
  
  pause(FPS^-1);
end
```

Which results in:

[image]

---

If you want white circles on a black background, replace the figure creation code with the following:

```matlab
figure('Color', 'k'); 
hP(1) = plot3(P(:,1,1), P(:,2,1), P(:,3,1), '.', 'Color', [0 0 0]+0.2, 'MarkerSize', 20); hold on;
hP(2) = plot3(P(:,1,2), P(:,2,2), P(:,3,2), '.', 'Color', [0 0 0]+0.4, 'MarkerSize', 20);
hP(3) = plot3(P(:,1,3), P(:,2,3), P(:,3,3), '.', 'Color', [0 0 0]+1.0, 'MarkerSize', 20);
AX_LIMS = [-1 1]*3;
drawnow; set(gca, 'XLim', AX_LIMS, 'YLim', AX_LIMS, 'ZLim', AX_LIMS, 'Color', 'k',...
  'XColor', 'k', 'YColor', 'k', 'ZColor', 'k');
```

Which then results in:

[image]

---

To export a plot as a movie file, you would need to use [`getframe`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html) inside the loop, and then use `VideoWriter` as explained in [this example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter.html#busy5fx-1_sep_bus0tu7).

Also, I've added the "trails" for aesthetic purposes, but these are easy to remove if you don't need them.

Comment: Thanks, I have to display a "movie" as an experiment in Neuroscience, rather than a plot. It needs to have a black background with white dots moving randomly on the screen. I have indeed found a few codes that plot 3d dots, but nothing on how to generate frames in order to create a movie of random dots moving in a 3D space.

Comment: @Kathia Ah, you've never mentioned this in your question. You need to separate your problem into several steps. This was the step of creating a 3d animation. Another step would be to color it according to your preferences (black background, remove the axes, etc.). Finally, exporting it is the 3rd problem. Separately, none of these problems are difficult, but together they might seem overwhelming. I only wonder - how are you planning to display a 3D movie? What are you currently missing in my answer?

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much for your answer and solution.  Well, I managed to create an optic flow movie, and I saved the frames in a file. Then I created another script to play the movie. With the optic flow, it was easy to create the 3D depth. Thanks for the plot solution. Is there a reason why some dots appear grey and not white?

Comment: The gray points are exactly the "trails" I mentioned... When a point moves to new position its previous position becomes gray, and its second-to-last position becomes dark gray. It's just a way of showing the path which a point took by showing some limited history. As mentioned, it's easy to remove.

Comment: One last question: is it possible to control the length of the depth (z). For instance, I want to see more depth in the 3D where I could clearly distinguish the dots that are on the z-axis. With our animations, I could have thought that the dots are moving on a 2D space from visual observation -- I guess this might be due to the orthogonal projection?

Comment: The only way I can think of to get a "feel" of 3D movement is to modify the size of the point according to how far they are from the observer. I think, in that case, a [`scatter3`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html) plot would be more appropriate, because there one can easily control the size of the individual points.